# Angular not dynamically updating deferred HTML

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a dynamic site using Angular.  I'm trying to simulate delays in loading HTML by using `setTimeout` with `$q.defer`.  It works if I don't have the timeout, but as soon as I add the timeout the data isn't loaded.  It *does* get populated if I click between different views, so I know it's executing.  But Angular doesn't seem to be aware that it's finally available.

I've got an HTML file, with the following:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id='my-content' ng-view></div>

  <div id='footer'>
    footer here
    <a href="#!/">View 1</a> <a href="#!/view2">View 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's `view1.html`:

```
<div ng-include="'teasers.html'"></div>
```

Here's `teasers.html`:

```
<div class='column content' ng-repeat="teaser in data.teasers">
  <div class='button type-overlay' ng-class="{{ 'button-' + ($index + 1) }}">
    <div class='teaser-text'>
      <img class='button-background' ng-src='{{ teaser.img_src }}'>
      <span class='teaser-text'>{{ teaser.name }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'view2.html'
  });
});

app.factory('data', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    fetchTeasers: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve([
          {
            "name": "Teaser 1",
            "img_src": "SRC"
          },
          {
            "name": "Teaser 2",
            "img_src": "SRC"
          },
          {
            "name": "Teaser 3",
            "img_src": "SRC"
          },
          {
            "name": "Teaser 4",
            "img_src": "SRC"
          }
        ]);
      }, 5000);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the `controller.js`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, data) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.teasers = data.fetchTeasers();
}
```

**What do I need to do to get `deferred` working in Angular?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of window.setTimeout use angular timeout method: **$timeout**. Be sure to load it via DI.

```
$timeout(function(){
  // all your magic goes here
});
```

By the way, you could use setTimeout, but then you would need do call `$scope.$apply()` manually. In fact this is what angular does internally.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){ // all your magic goes here })
```

But again, as I said, just use $timeout.

PS. The reason view gets updated after user interaction is the fact that it invokes dirty checking, unfortunately a little bit too late in this case. Using $apply or $timeout will ensure that angular gets notified about the changes when needed.

PPS. Although I've posted an answer to this particular problem, I should mention that you in this case you could use `$resource`, which is a angular service supporting RESTful APIs with promises. It uses an implementation of deferreds based on $q as well. There's no need to reinvent the wheel, unless you have any good reasons for it.